# How to determine cefsharp version

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

How I can know which version of cefsharp, cefsharp chromium version I'm using? I guess there is a command like `//b/c` that I can use to know. Are there any other methods?

Also: What is the difference between cefsharp version and cefsharp chromium version?

Comment: If your using the `Nuget` packages then you can simply check your `packages.config` file. For further info on each release check https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the information you need is available in this url: `chrome://version/`. Just point the browser to that url and check out the first two values. They are the version of CEFSharp and the version number of Chromium in that order.

[image: CEF version]

*Image taken from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990346/Using-HTML-as-UI-Elements-in-a-WinForms-Applicatio)*

CEFSharp is a project that helps you embed the [Chromium web browser](https://www.chromium.org/Home) into your application. Since Chromium is a standalone project not affiliated with CEFSharp, it has its own version numbers as any other project. To support each new version of Chromium, CEFSharp developers need to make changes to their project, which in turn increases their version number.

Answer (score 6):

```
Cef.ChromiumVersion
```

That's it.  You can get the Chromium version just by calling this property.

Comment: See http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/T_CefSharp_Cef.htm#ID4RBToggle for similar version properties